# Run benchmark on method using completable future

Tags: java, java-8, benchmarking, completable-future, jmh

I'm trying to measure the performance of a particular method.
I run the benchmarks just fine when calling the method directly,
but when the method used a completable future with a custom executor everything collapsed. I've implemented the method to use a completable future in order to force a timeout if the method takes too long.

```
@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.SingleShotTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Threads(value = 5)
@Warmup(iterations = 20)
@Measurement(iterations = 50, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
public String very_big_query(TestState testState) throws Exception {
    return testState.transpiler.process(testState.veryBigQuery);
}
```

---

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
public static class TestState {
    String veryBigQuery;
    Transpiler transpiler;

    @Setup(Level.Trial)
    public void doSetupTrial() throws Exception {
        veryBigQuery = "(";
        for(int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
            veryBigQuery += String.format("java_%s OR ", i);
        }
        veryBigQuery += "java_100) AND (";
        for(int i = 100; i < 199; i++) {
            veryBigQuery += String.format("java_%s OR ", i);
        }
        veryBigQuery += String.format("java_%s)", 200);
    }

    @Setup(Level.Invocation)
    public void doSetupInvocation() throws Exception {
        random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, productionQueries.size());
        randomQuery = productionQueries.get(random);
        transpiler = new Transpiler(5, 100); //number of threads in custom pool for the executor, timeout in milliseconds
    }
}
```

---

```
public String process(final String input) throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        return SOME_STRING;
    }, executor);

    return cf.get(timeoutInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

---

```
this.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
```

I get this error

> JMH had finished, but forked VM did not exit, are there stray running
>   threads? Waiting 24 seconds more...
>
> Non-finished threads:

Can someone explain to me why is this happening and how do I approach it in order to make it work?

Comment: what is `Transliper`?

Comment: Would seem that you need to wait for the threads to finish! That the problem with running things asynchronously...

Comment: @Eugene a custom class that contains the method process. It doesn't have a state and and the method process uses a completable future to do the actual processing, with an executor of fixed thread pool.

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: @BoristheSpider can you elaborate? I'm always calling get inside process, so basically process is a synchronous method (as far as the outside world is concerned) with a timeout policy.

Comment: Do I need to expose the executor in order to shut it down in every benchmark? When going to production the executor will never be shut down.

Comment: this entire test looks fishy to me, two `@SetUp` methods, `Level.Invocation`, which is documented to be very dangerous, a `CompletableFuture` that supplies something on *each* call... if you could explain in plain english what you are trying to measure may be... I have not done too much multi-threaded code in `JMH`, but i bet the samples would help you quite a lot

Comment: process doesn't need to have a completable future implementation, it's just for enforcing a timeout. The actual functionality is that it generates a tree and traverses it, but that shouldn't matter, it's isolated (moreover I cannot post it here, unfortunately). Level.Invocation is dangerous? Do you have a link to read about that?

Comment: Ok found some bibliography about invocation and changed it to trial. Thanks for the heads up. The same problem remains though.

Comment: Ok now everything works. I exposed the executor and I shut it down with tear down annotation. @Eugene if you would like please provide an answer stating to change the level and use a tear down phase for the executor, so I can accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First be sure to go through the samples of `JMH`, it is very easy to shoot yourself in the foot with these configs (I write tests via JMH once a week probably) and still mess things up every time.

Then, get rid of `Level.Invocation` unless you really understand what it does...

And last may be shut down the executor in a `@TearDown` method.